# How do I get change a tag html changed?

Tags: jquery, html, onchange

https://jsfiddle.net/doksul/1mc0y33k/

When i click submit button, change html a tag
But jquery change event didn't catch this.

How do I get change html a tag text changed?

```
$('#aTag').change(function() {
  $('#textReulst').val('changed');
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
  $('#aTag').html('123');
});
```

Comment: i think trigger is not best answer. :( if any other side change html must be get in code trigger. how do i better code this?

Comment: You can easily find this by googling.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an event for [DOM change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.change()` event is limited to `[input]` elements, `[textarea]` boxes and `[select]` elements. For `[select]`, `[input:type=checkbox]`, and `[input:type=radio]` buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the `event` is deferred until the element loses focus.

I guess you are bind change event to other type of elements, you need manually trigger event after `innerHtml` changes.

Comment: it's only for trigger way? :(

Comment: yes, jquery doesn't watch innerHtml changes, that means it does not fire event after $('#aTag').html('123');

Answer (score 3):

Hello Please use following code, trigger your change event after clicking on submit:

```
$('#aTag').change(function() {
   $('#textReulst').val('changed');
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
   $('#aTag').html('123');
   $("#aTag").trigger("change");
});
```

Use this JS Fiddle URL :
https://jsfiddle.net/1mc0y33k/3/

Answer (score 0):

i did a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u72w3uag/), thing is you need to trigger the `change` event on anchor tag, like this.

```
 $('#aTag').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function txtchange(){
  $('#textReulst').val('changed');
}

$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#aTag').html('2222');
    txtchange();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger your .change function.

```
$('#aTag').change(function() {
  $('#textReulst').val('changed');
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#aTag').html('123');
    $( "#aTag" ).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a jquery trigger api for the functionality you want.

For that you can create a new custom jquery Api like as below

```
jQuery.fn.htmlChange = function (new_html) {
    $(this).html(new_html);
    $(this).trigger('change');
};
```

and calling the above Api when you need to trigger the change event whenever the markup is updated.

You can call the above function like below

```
$('#aTag').htmlChange('123');
```

Here is the working sample [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1mc0y33k/1/)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Here i do not use trigger take a look **UPADATED** : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6sohLjff/5/)

Hope this is help you.Use trigger for your result. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sohLjff/4/)

Add this:

```
  $('#aTag').change(function() {
  $('#submit').val('changed');
});

  $('#textReulst').click(function() {
  $('#aTag').html('123');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i think trigger is not best answer. :( if any other side change html must be get in code trigger. how do i better code this?